# Adding images with API currencies text at DropDown widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a currency converter with API from free.currconv.com. I'm trying to figure out how to put country flag with currencies text in DropDown widget.
This is an example for my problem(from YouTube).

[image]

This is my code in `customwidgets.dart`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget customizedDropDown(
    List<String> items,
    String value,
    void onChange(val)
    ){
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 4.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color:  Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      ),
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: value,
        onChanged: (String val){
          onChange(val);
        },
        items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String val){
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(val),
            value: val,
          );
    }).toList(),
      ),
    );
}
```

I have an `assets/images` of the 33 country flags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the child of `DropdownMenuItem` to a row with an image and a text, like this:

```
      DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250?image=9', width: 20),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Text('hi'),
          ],
        ),
        value: val,
      )
```

But of course, replace the image with your local image.